# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com" when attempting to connect to ECR from an EC2 instance

aws ecr list-images --repository-name myrepo

ECR (Container Registry) is available in my region us-west-1 and yet I get the error

I believe there are some permissions and roles and credential file tweaking activities that may resolve this.  I have created an IAM role giving full ECR access and attached it to this instance, rebooted it and yet no change.  Any help or insight or faint glimmer of hope accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: Does your instance have internet access?

Comment: If your instance doesn't have internet access (which seems to be the case) then you'll need a VPC Endpoint for ECR

Comment: I was able to successfully connect and do my work when I used
https://ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com instead - i.e. without the "api." prefix.  This suggests that it is not a network access issue but likely to be a routing problem inside AWS network config. AWS developer paid support were not very helpful either even after I explained this to them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Subnet (and route table) for your instance.
Even if it's a public subnet, having a rule for `10.0.0.0/20 -> local` may make ECR unreachable. (specifically at the URLs:
`api.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com` and `<account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com`)

You likely have to move the instance (or start a new instance) in a different VPC or subnet that has an appropriate route table. Make sure that the EC2 is in a subnet, with a route table that can access ECR. Ex: for the default VPC,
0.0.0.0/0 to Internet Gateway
172.31.0.0/16 to local
will allow access